# How to use deferred method in ajax to speed up data loading from php script?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I came across this example of fetching data in parallel way via `ajax`. However I don't quite understand this. Can someone tell me how to fetch these data from php script and append to a div in the same way shown below please?

Especially what does this line mean? `globalStore.html = html;` Fetching html type of data and copy into `global.html` page? and then in the `$then` section fetch data from that page and append?

My aim is to divide a single ajax request into at least 3 into 3 different php pages and then display the array of data into the appended div.

```
$.when(
    // Get the HTML
    $.get("/feature/", function(html) {
        globalStore.html = html;
    }),

    // Get the CSS
    $.get("/assets/feature.css", function(css) {
        globalStore.css = css;
    }),

    // Get the JS
    $.getScript("/assets/feature.js")

).then(function() {

    // All is ready now, so...

    // Add CSS to page
    $("<style />").html(globalStore.css).appendTo("head");

    // Add HTML to page
    $("body").append(globalStore.html);

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unnecessary at best to render a page like that as modern browsers will pull down multiple resources in parallel anyway (with the possible exception of the script), but that's a different question so to answer yours:

```
$.get("/feature/", function(html) {
    globalStore.html = html;
})
```

what that's doing is assigning the callback from the $.get, here called `html`, to the object variable `globalStore` presumably defined above this code. Same for the css call, and then no callback is necessary for the $.getScript. All of these ajax calls are jQuery deferred objects wrapped inside a $.when which itself returns a new "master" deferred object, on which a $.then callback is attached. This callback is triggered when all of its "children" deferreds have resolved, and then it manipulates the DOM with the data it stored in `globalStore` from the ajax calls.

To put this to use in a `<div>` instead - say you want to load prices from 3 different vendors but show them all at the same time - you'd follow the same general principle and just manipulate a different portion of the dom (namely your appended div).

Suggest you read https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/ in its entirety.

Comment: @swornabsent..if the data type is json can i simply replace the css in bracket with json?

Comment: @Vani yes, the `css` in `$.get("/assets/feature.css", function(css) {` is just an arbitrary variable name, you can make that whatever you want. You might want to specify the correct dataType though, see the bottom example of https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/